# PySpark Reduce on RDD with only single element

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, reduce

Is there anyway to deal with RDDs with only a single element (this can sometimes happen for what I am doing)? When that's the case, reduce stops working as the operation requires 2 inputs.

I am working with key-value pairs such as:

```
(key1, 10),
(key2, 20),
```

And I want to aggregate their values, so the result should be:

```
30
```

But there are cases where the rdd  only contain a single key-value pair, so reduce does not work here, example:

```
(key1, 10)
```

This will return nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a `.values()` before doing `reduce`, it should work even if there is only 1 element in the RDD:

```
from operator import add

rdd = sc.parallelize([('key1', 10),])

rdd.values().reduce(add)
# 10
```

Comment: I was having issue with my method

Comment: Now I use ```.values().fold(0, lambda x,y: x+y)``` and seem to fixed the problem. Thanks a lot, friend.